# (VBA) Referenciar un rango con nombre

Tags: excel, vba, names

Muy buenos dias, tardes o noches.
Soy nuevo en esta plataforma por lo que pido perdón si no me aclaro mi problema eficazmente

Mi problema consiste en que requiero referenciar un rango con nombre (Por ejemplo, "Semestre11", que seria toda una columna especifica), y la cosa es que tengo muchas restricciones para poder llevar el programa:

-Es un sistema de adaptacion: Se introducirán nuevas hojas con cualquier nombre, y cosas asi, idee un sistema por formulario que asigna automaticamente segun donde se seleccione los datos de interes para que tengan un nombre y poder citarlos en otros

-No podria ser algun tipo de Userform: ya que el programa ya esta un poco complejo y no seria acorde al trabajo

Y es en esto lo que necesito ayuda
tengo una variable (as string) que es Fl, de forma que

```
Dim Fl as string
Fl = [Semestre11].address
```

Pero eso me devuelve solo la columna (A:A), y necesito que me devuelva la columna y la hoja (BD!A:A)

Comment: La propiedad `address` devuelte en texto la dirección. Si necesitas la referencia completa, incluyendo el nombre de la hoja, prueba con `[Semestre11].address(,,,True)`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si sirvio!!!